# Retrieving JSON from PHP File, and Append inside div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Im trying to do near real time graph update within my site. To do this im trying to basically reload a php file every 30 seconds. I made the data of PHP dynamically echo out json code as shown below. Ad inside the file is also `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">` which refreshes the file to recheck database.

`{"todayCalculateCR":"5%"}{"todayEPC":"0.20"}{"todayCTR":"34%"}{"yesterdayCalculateCR":"35%"}{"yesterdayEPC":"0.03"}{"yesterdayCTR":"24%"}{"monthCalculateCR":"14%"}{"monthEPC":"0.07"}{"monthCTR":"24%"}`

Basically now i want some jquery code to place on my index.php page to load this file, interpret the json code and append the data to the correct divs.

Example:
`<div class="yesterdayEPC">0.03</div>`

Ive been looking on jquery.com and on stack overflow for ways to basically take the above json data and append it.

`$.get( "dashboard-stats.php", function( data ) {
  $( "body" )
    .append( "yesterdayEPC: " + data.yesterdayEPC ) // John
    .append( "Time: " + data.yesterdayEPC ); //  2pm
}, "json" );`

This is brief of PHP file making json:

`$month_visits = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`locker_reports`WHERE`uid`= '$user_id' AND`month`= '$month_date'"));
    $month_clicks = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`reports`WHERE`uid`= '$user_id' AND`month`= '$month_date' AND`status`= '1'"));
    $month_leads = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`reports`WHERE`uid`= '$user_id' AND`month`= '$month_date' AND`status`= '2'"));
    if($month_leads == "" || $month_clicks == "") 
    {
        echo json_encode(array("monthCalculateCR"=>"n/a"));
        echo json_encode(array("monthEPC"=>"n/a"));
    }
    else 
    {
        $monthCalculateCR = number_format($month_clicks / $month_leads)."%";
        echo json_encode(array("monthCalculateCR"=>"".$monthCalculateCR.""));
        $monthEPC = number_format($month_leads / $month_clicks, 2)."";
        echo json_encode(array("monthEPC"=>"".$monthEPC.""));
    }
    if($month_visits == "")
    {
        echo json_encode(array("monthCTR"=>"n/a"));
    }
    else
    {
        $monthCTR = number_format($month_clicks / $month_visits, 2) * 100 . "%";
        echo json_encode(array("monthCTR"=>"".$monthCTR.""));
    }`

Comment: you should read up on socket.io since that would tackle your problem more approrietly http://socket.io/

Comment: do you have tried any code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `setTimeout` function to call the `$.get()` jQuery method to recall the php file that echos the JSON.

```
reload();

function reload(){
    $.get( "yourFile.php", function( data ) {
      //update table based on data
      var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#myDiv').append('callback called').append(data);
    });
    setTimeout(reload, 30000);
}
```

Comment: Ok but how do i get json URL i have no clue how to get the json data from php

Comment: Suggestion: change `setTimeout` to `window.setTimeout` and put it inside the callback function. @MrJohnson you fetch the data and return it using `json_encode`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Why I should use `window.setTimeout` instead `setTimeout`? If I put setTimeout in the callback function the reload time is not 30 second but depends on the answer time of the php file and in case of error the page will not be refreshed anymore

Comment: In case of error, you want error handling I guess. The `setTimeout` method is within the `window` object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @MrJohnson - You have to create a new php file that retrive the datas from the database and sends they back with echo after encoded with `json_encode`

Comment: Above is what i receive from my php file im not sure if its correct jso format because none of example from jquery works for me

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Ok, it's a method of `window` object, but wich is the difference if I don't use `window.` before `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @MrJohnson - in `jsonData` you have the answered data from the php file to display. Maybe the better way is to build an array in the php file that contains all the datas and use only one echo to send all back. It's easier because you should not check which respons it is

Comment: You call the php file with the `$.get()` method and for every echo written on the php file the callback function will be called. So for test you can append the recived data in one div like in my code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by basically making the json in 1 bracket.

Then using a tutorial I found out I can do below.

`Todayclicks: <span id="clicks">`

```
<script>

var JSONObject = {"todayEarnings":"2.60","todayVisits":"62","todayClicks":"26","todayLeads":"3","todayCalculateCR":"9%","todayEPC":"0.12","todayCTR":"42%","yesterdayEarnings":"0.40","yesterdayClicks":"35","yesterdayVisits":"148","yesterdayLeads":"1","yesterdayCalculateCR":"35%","yesterdayEPC":"0.03","yesterdayCTR":"24%","monthEarnings":"3.00","monthClicks":"65","monthVisits":"242","monthLeads":"4","monthCalculateCR":"16%","monthEPC":"0.06","monthCTR":"27%"}

document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=JSONObject.todayClicks;

</script>
```